# Prism BindableBase.SetProperty()

Tags: c#, prism

I am developing a ViewModel based on BindableBase.
This VM holds an instance of a domain model.
The VM exposes a property, say Name from which I want to not use local storage (i.e. storage in VM), but rather delegate to the model object's property.
I would like to use SetProperty(), but the storage reference cannot be a property.
Do I have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged my self ?
Is it at all a good idea to delegate to the model this way ?
Would it be possible to extend BindableBase (or team to add) to cover for this ?

Comment: Can you post some code so we can understand what you are asking.  I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: I am newbie to starting StackOverflow threads, it seems like the comment field is quite limited in size so I will post more than one comment du to this:

Comment: I think there is at least 3 approaches to property binding:

1: Bind directly to the model's property which exposes the Model to the view. I would like to avoid this.

2: Bind to a property of the ViewModel which in turn access the property of the Model.

3: The purist way; Bind to a property of the ViewModel which is totally isolated from the Model.

Approach 2 is (I guess) the practical approach assuming one-to-one relation to the Model's property.

Approach 3 is (I guess) neccessary if there is not a one-to-one relation (e.g. a calculated property of some kind).

Comment: Approach 2 does not need any private variable defined in the ViewModel since it accesses the Models property.

Approach 3 need a local variable defined in the ViewModel.

Comment: If I want to use approach 2, then I do not see any way to use SetProperty() from the ViewModel's property setter (unless the backing store of the Model's property exists and is public which is a no-no), e.g
SetProperty(ref TheModel.TheProperty, value) is not working (does not compile because a ref parameter must be a variable, not a property) and it seems like I have to handle this with my own implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged.

Could this be done by implementing SetProperty() to take a delegate or an action as an overload ?
Or do I misunderstand something obvious ?

Comment: Do you still want some code posted ?

Answer (score 6):

So first you must chose how you will architect your VMs and Models.  As you mentioned, there are a few options.  The easiest and the way I recommend, is to just expose your Model as a property and then bind your View to the model properties:

```
public class MyViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private Person _myPerson;
    public Person Person
    {
        get { return _myPerson; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _myPerson, value); }
    } 
}
```

If you don't want to do that and would rather wrap each individual model property, you would do it like this.

```
public class MyViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private Person _myPerson;

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _myPerson.Name; }
        set { _myPerson.Name = value }
    } 
}
```

Keep in mind, your Person model object still has to implement INPC.

EDIT:  If you don't have control over your models and need them to implement INPC, you could try to use IL weaving, or create a façade/decorator for your models and wrap them individually.

```
public class MyPersonFacade : BindableBase
{
    private Person _myPerson;

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _myPerson.Name; }
        set 
        {
            _myPerson.Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    } 
}
```

Then use this as your Model in your VM.

Comment: Please assume that model is Legacy and INPC is not an option

Comment: then you create a façade around your model and implement INPC.  So you would have a PersonFacade that wraps each property and calls INPC.  You can't use SetProperty when doing this.

Comment: Ok, Thanks.
Seems like it is not "possible" to overload the SetProperty method to take another property instead of the local backing store then.
I can live with my "own" implementation of INPC (RaisePropertyChanged using CallerMemberName attribute etc.)

Comment: You can still use Bindablebase and just call OnpropertyChanged() because it already implement INPC and uses the CallerMemberNameAttribute.  See my edited answer

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged()` is now obsolete and you should use `RaisePropertyChanged()` instead.