# Binding to the model for property changes

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, prism

On another post ([Prism BindableBase.SetProperty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726294/prism-bindablebase-setproperty)), @brian-lagunas said he prefers to expose the Model as a property and bind the View to the model properties.  He gave the following example code:

```
 public class MyViewModel : BindableBase
 {
     private Person _myPerson;
     public Person Person
     {
         get { return _myPerson; }
         set { SetProperty(ref _myPerson, value); }
     } 
 }
```

However, I'm unsure how I'm to bind to the properties.  Does this notify of property changes?

Update:
Is this how I would implement INPC on the model?  If so, what have I gained that I would not have had by putting the properties in the view model which already supports INPC?

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _FirstName;
    private string _LastName;
    public string FirstName { get { return _FirstName; } set => SetProperty(ref _FirstName, value); }
    public string LastName { get { return _LastName; } set => SetProperty(ref _LastName, value); }
    private void SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!Equals(storage,value))
        {
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the following model:

```
public class Person
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Binding to the `FirstName` property, any update to FirstName would not have a notification of property changes. The only way to accomplish this is if your model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

That said, binding directly to a model can be an excellent strategy. As a common example if you have a `ListView`, you can usually bind to an `ObservableCollection<SomeModel>` safely. If you're working with a relatively small dataset and can afford the overhead of reloading your data source then your pretty safe all the way around.

Now as far as how to bind to a property, given:

```
public class ViewAViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private Person _myPerson;
    public Person MyPerson
    {
        get { return _myPerson; }
        set { SetProperty( ref _myPerson, value ); }
    }
}
```

Your XAML Markup would look something like:

```
<Label Text="{Binding MyPerson.FirstName}" />
```

**UPDATE:**

As described in your updated question, yes you could implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` like that. Remember it's already done for you with `BindableBase` so given your example you could simply inherit from `BindableBase`... Another good option is if you use [MvvmHelpers](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers) from James Montemagno you could use his `ObservableObject` on your Models and the `BaseViewModel` for your ViewModels which gives you properties like Title, SubTitle, Icon, IsBusy, IsNotBusy.

The benefit of doing this of course is that you now have an ability to bind directly to a Model. A View rarely knows just about a Model consider the following:

**Person Model**

```
public class Person : BindableBase
{
    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { SetProperty( ref _firstName, value ); }
    }

    private string _lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { SetProperty( ref _lastName, value ); }
    }

    private DateTime _dob;
    public DateTime DOB
    {
        get { return _dob; }
        set { SetProperty( ref _dob, value ); }
    }
}
```

**User Profile ViewModel**

```
public class UserProfileViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    INavigationService _navigationService { get; }
    IPageDialogService _pageDialogService { get; }

    public UserProfileViewModel( INavigationService navigationService, IPageDialogService pageDialogService )
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        _pageDialogService = pageDialogService;
        DoFooCommand = new DelegateCommand( () => _pageDialogService.DisplayAlertAsync( "Alert", "Foo", "Ok" ) );
    }

    private bool shouldSave = false;

    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { SetProperty( ref _title, value ); }
    }

    private Person _user;
    public Person User
    {
        get { return _user; }
        set { SetProperty( ref _user, value ); }
    }

    public DelegateCommand DoFooCommand { get; }

    public void OnNavigatingTo( NavigationParameters parameters )
    {
        Title = AppResources.UserProfilePageTitle;
        User = parameters.GetValue<Person>( "currentUser" );
        User.PropertyChanged += ( sender, e ) => shouldSave = true;
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom( NavigationParameters parameters )
    {
        if( shouldSave )
        {
            // Do your persistence here.
        }
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo( NavigationParameters parameters )
    {
        User.DOB = new DateTime( 2017, 1, 1 );
    }
}
```

**User Profile View**

```
<ContentPage Title="{Binding Title}">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="First Name" />
        <Entry Text="{Binding User.FirstName}" />
        <Label Text="Last Name" />
        <Entry Text="{Binding User.LastName}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding User.DOB}" />
        <Button Text="Do Foo" Command="{Binding DoFooCommand}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Given this code there should be a couple of things worth noting:

1) Our ViewModel consists of various things that have nothing what so ever to do with our Model like Commands, or properties like the Title. It is also likely consuming various services like the `INavigationService` or `IPageDialogService`

2) Second we may want to restrict which properties a user can edit and the ViewModel can edit.

3) If our model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` we can attach an event handler to let us know that our model changed after we set it so we can persist those changes.

4) It makes the XAML more readable about our intent. We aren't binding to some magic property called FirstName. We are really binding to our Person model's FirstName property.

Comment: I've updated my question to add the implementation of INPC.  What have I gained over having the properties in the view model which already implements INPC?

Comment: It's becoming clearer.  Thanks for hanging in there with me.  In your View Model, you have a property for the User with a backing field.  What does that accomplish?  Why not just have an auto-implemented property?

Comment: Technically it shouldn't need it since the model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, however I tend to do it by convention on everything but an `ObservableCollection` or other custom Observable Type that is explicitly named `Observable`. It ensures better code readability.

Comment: Apparently, the property for the User is required to link the View with the Model through the ViewModel.  I tried it without it, and the View did not properly bind with the Model.

Comment: I am using this approach for my model class. However, now I want to notify a `DelegateCommand` that one of my model's properties has changed, using `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`. My instinct was to put this after the `SetProperty()` line of the class object in the ViewModel. But, this doesn't work... even though I have used this same approach on properties defined directly in the ViewModel and that works fine. How should I implement this?

Comment: @r_laezza this is a completely different question. please open a new thread

Answer (score 0):

> I'm unsure how I'm to bind to the properties.

To bind to properties of model you have to data bind to property which exposes model and its property, i.e. if you have exposed your model with property 'Person'
and want to bind to Name property of person, you'll need no bind to 'Person.Name'.

> Does this notify of property changes?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn736263(v=pandp.50).aspx

SetProperty method will take care of notifying property change.

Comment: I understand that SetProperty will handle the notification, but Brian uses SetProperty on the Model, not the property.  If the property changes, will the notification be sent?

Comment: Yes, but it'll be your model who'll send property changed notification, and as the post mentions, your model needs to implement INPC

Comment: So what do I gain by exposing the Model as a property?  What effect does the SetProperty call have on the Model?

Comment: What you gain is that you only have *one* property in the view model that will gain you access to *ALL* properties in the model, via dot notation. The alternative would be to have matching properties in both the view model and model. If you have ever tried that, you find out very quickly that adding new properties to the model means adding them to the view model, too. It quickly becomes a coder's nightmare. The `SetProperty` function sets the properties value, and makes sure that the notifications are fired, so your UI binding will update. It is there for your convenience, please use it!

Comment: @R.Richards So, even though you do not specify the SetProperty method on each of the setters for the properties of the Model, it calls it?  How would I go about implementing validation such as using the INotifyDataErrorInfo interface?  I'm using EF6, so the entities are also used for the database.  Is this going to cause a problem?  It seems it would.

Comment: Wouldn't you also need a backing field for each property to call the SetProperty method on?

Comment: We are exposing model object as a property so that you don't have to do that in ViewModel, given that, model implements INPC